# Mutating model data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model

I want to manipulate data in my model how would I do that? I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

```
class Character extends Model
{
    //Get players by level
    public function scopeGetPlayersByLevel($query){
       $output = $query->orderBy('level', 'desc')->get();
       $output->classid = 100;
       return $output;
    }

    //Get online status
    public function account(){
        $account = $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'account_name', 'username');
        $account->online = $account->online == 1 ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
        return $account;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect and what is returned ?

Comment: I expect from the `$account->online` variable to return `Online` but it still returns `1`

Comment: try `$account->onlineStatus = $account->online ? 'Online' : 'Offline';` See if this works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$account = $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'account_name', 'username');` doesn't return what you think it does. Try defining a belongs to relationship (let's call it `account()`). And then doing this (with accessor as Alexey pointed out): `return $this->account->online ? 'Online' : 'Offline'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Define an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in the `Account` model:

```
public function getOnlineAttribute($value)
{
    return $value === 1 ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this in the view? Or do I have to add this as a variable in the controller with compose?

Comment: It'll just convert `1` to `Online ` when you'll try to access this property from any part of your app.

Comment: Ahh I get it. My mistake was that I was adding the method to the Character model which was joining the Account model. When I added the method to Account it did work. Thank you!

Comment: I'm new to Laravel but I'm already in love with the framework it works great

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

a) Define a relationship for account model

b) Make an accessor (I called it getAccountStrAttribute, which means you call it like this: `$acc->account_str`).

c) Win

```
class Character extends Model
{
    // Relationship defined
    public function account() {
      return $query->belongsTo(Account::class, 'account_name', 'username');
    }

    //Get online status
    public function getAccountStrAttribute(){
        return $this->account->online ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
    }

    // I can't figure out what you want this function to return/do :/
    //Get players by level
    public function scopeGetPlayersByLevel($query){
       $output = $query->orderBy('level', 'desc')->get();
       $output->classid = 100;
       return $output;
    }
}
```